# How to override document hooks in knitr / quarto?

Tags: knitr, quarto

In a Quarto document created in RStudio, I would generally like to have no decimals when I include inline code. So, I add a document hook. But, sometimes I do want decimals. How can I override the document hook in these cases? Here is an example with a hook and my (failed) attempt to override the hook by explicitly calling the `round` function:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
---

```{r setup}
#| include: false

knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {   
  if(!is.numeric(x)){     x   }
  else{    prettyNum(round(x,0), big.mark=",")    } 
  })

```
`r round(1.2345, 2)`
````

I want the result to be 1.23, but instead it prints as 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be to put the inline numeric number in a non-numeric format such that the above defined functions skips it, e.g.

```
`r as.character(round(1.2345, 2))`
```